# Jolt convert array keys

Tags: jolt

I want to convert keys in array json by using jolt
Input

```
[
  {
    "TestString": "AGC",
    "TestNumber": "3"
  },
  {
    "TestString": "DDD",
    "TestNumber": "2"
  }
]
```

Out put:

```
[
  {
    "test_string": "AGC",
    "test_number": "3"
  },
  {
    "test_string": "DDD",
    "test_number": "2"
  }
]
```

What is jolt spec will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  [{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "TestString": "[&1].test_string",
        "TestNumber": "[&1].test_number"
      }
    }
  }]
```